# Magento 2 - How to get a list of newly created products on homepage

Tags: magento2, admin, layout, magento2.3, frontend

how I can get a list of newly created products? I want to display in frontend the latest added products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you want a new product collection depends `created_at`field.

So, you have to create a block class at your module and at that block class, you have to create a product collection and sort by DESCENDING  `created_at` ORDER.

I have create a block class at here depends on the structure of [`Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\NewProduct`](https://github.com/devamitbera/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/NewProduct.php#L15) and that block class must be extended

`Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct` implement `agento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface`

At `_getProductCollection()` ,I build that a product collection and sort by created_at desc.

```
<?php

namespace {VendorName}\Catalog\Block\Product;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Context as CustomerContext;

/**
 * New products block
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.LongVariable)
 */
class NewProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct implements
    \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface
{
    /**
     * Default value for products count that will be shown
     */
    const DEFAULT_PRODUCTS_COUNT = 10;

    /**
     * Products count
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $_productsCount;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
     */
    protected $httpContext;

    /**
     * Catalog product visibility
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility
     */
    protected $_catalogProductVisibility;

    /**
     * Product collection factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $catalogProductVisibility
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->_catalogProductVisibility = $catalogProductVisibility;
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $data
        );
    }

    /**
     * Initialize block's cache
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('empty', 6)
            ->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('1column', 5)
            ->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('2columns-left', 4)
            ->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('2columns-right', 4)
            ->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('3columns', 3);

        $this->addData(
            ['cache_lifetime' => 86400, 'cache_tags' => [\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::CACHE_TAG]]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get Key pieces for caching block content
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCacheKeyInfo()
    {
        return [
           'CATALOG_PRODUCT_CREATED_BY_DESC',
           $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId(),
           $this->_design->getDesignTheme()->getId(),
           $this->httpContext->getValue(CustomerContext::CONTEXT_GROUP),
           'template' => $this->getTemplate(),
           $this->getProductsCount()
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Prepare and return product collection
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection|Object|\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection
     */
    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {


        /** @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection */
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->setVisibility($this->_catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

        $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices(
            $collection
        )->addStoreFilter()->addAttributeToSort(
            'created_at',
            'desc'
        )->setPageSize(
            $this->getProductsCount()
        )->setCurPage(
            1
        );

        return $collection;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare collection with new products
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock
     */
    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $this->setProductCollection($this->_getProductCollection());
        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }

    /**
     * Set how much product should be displayed at once.
     *
     * @param int $count
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setProductsCount($count)
    {
        $this->_productsCount = $count;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get how much products should be displayed at once.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getProductsCount()
    {
        if (null === $this->_productsCount) {
            $this->_productsCount = self::DEFAULT_PRODUCTS_COUNT;
        }
        return $this->_productsCount;
    }

    /**
     * Return identifiers for produced content
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getIdentities()
    {
        return [\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::CACHE_TAG];
    }
}
```

Call this Block class from `cms_index_index.xml` layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content.aside">
            <block class="{VendorName}\{ModuleName}\Block\Product\NewProduct" name="catalog.product.related" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">new</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="new.product.addto" as="addto">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                           name="new.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                           template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
     </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Try Below way. 
Create your block file and add below code

```
<?php
namespace YourCompanyName\YourModuleName\Block;
class YourCustomBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{ 
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    protected $_productVisibility;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context, 
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory; 
        $this->_productVisibility = $productVisibility; 
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getProductCollection() {
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        // filter current website products
        $collection->addWebsiteFilter();

        $collection->addAttributeToSort('entity_id','desc');

        // filter current store products
        $collection->addStoreFilter();

        // set visibility filter
        $collection->setVisibility($this->productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds());

        // fetching only 5 products
        $collection->setPageSize(5); 

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

and your phtml file call yor block

```
$productCollection = $block->getProductCollection(); 
foreach ($productCollection as $product) { 
    echo $product->getId() . '<br />';
    echo $product->getName() . '<br />';
}
```

> using object manager

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 

$productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$collection = $productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

// filter current website products
$collection->addWebsiteFilter();

$collection->addAttributeToSort('entity_id','desc');

// filter current store products
$collection->addStoreFilter();

// set visibility filter
$collection->setVisibility($objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility')->getVisibleInSiteIds());

// fetching only 5 products
$collection->setPageSize(5); 
    foreach ($productCollection as $product) { 
    echo $product->getId() . '<br />';
    echo $product->getName() . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it can be done via admin :
Create a Cms Block , and as a content , inser a widget :
[image]

- Add widget type : Catalog Product List

[image]

- Set Number of Products to Display: (usually is used 4 )
- Tempate : Products Grid Template
- For your request to be the New Products : You can either use a
  condition to set up a category for the new products.
  Or you dont wont the condition , insert the widget of New Products directly:
  [image]
  Attach the cms block you created into your homepage .

Answer (score 0):

To add a list of new products on the home page of your website you can follow the below instructions

**1st Method**

- Go to the following location

  > Admin (backend) > Content > Elements > Widgets
- Click on the Add Widgets.
- In **`Settings`** section select **Type => Catalog new Product List** & select your **theme** & press to **continue**.
- In **`Storefront Properties`** section give a **title** to your **widgets** & select your **store**.
- In the Layout Updates click on the **Add Layout Updates** button.
- Select Specified Page into the Display on Section.
  -In the new generated section select your page & the area where you want to load the widgets.
- In the **`Widgets`** options section select **New Products** in the **Display Type**
- Select the other options as per your requirement like **Display Page Control**, **Number of Products to Display**, **Cache Lifetime**.
- Click on the save button.

**2nd Method**

- Go to below location

  > Admin (backend) > Content > Elements > Pages
- Select your Page(Home Page in your case).
- In the content section click on the Show/Hide Editor.
- Paste the below code at your desired place

**Code:**

```
{{widget type="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\NewWidget" display_type="new_products" show_pager="1" products_per_page="5" products_count="10" template="product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml" page_var_name="pmbfrt" type_name="Catalog New Products List"}}
```